# How to fill out multi-field activity via other activities?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

I have a multi-field activity (**MainActivity**)
To fill out these fields, I need to switch to another activity (**FirstActivity**), select some data there and go back (to **MainActivity**).
Then I need to go to another activity (**SecondActivity**), select some data there and go back (to **MainActivity**).
In the end, I should be on the filled **MainActivity** with the first and second data.

It occurred to me to set static fields, but this is a bad solution.
To drag all the data in `Intent` through all the activities is also an ugly solution.

Are there any other options how can I do this?

Comment: You can use database to store the data you want to select in other activities and then retrieve it in MainActivity. Or you could just use Preferences if the data is small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user shared preferences to store temporary data on device from every activity and on the final activity retrieve all data from Shared Preferences and fill-out all the fields and at the end after using that data, remove all data from shared preferences.That's it.

You can also use sqlite database for this purpose.

Here is a tutorial for shared preferences :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: I think, that shared preferences is deprecated feature and it doesn't recommended to use

Comment: No way brother. I am using shared preferences in my project.

Here you can check official documentation.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Comment: I can do this task for you. If you can share your code with me.

Answer (score 0):

Use basic Intent to go to the first activity from Mainactivity,

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

then select data from first activity and send the data ;

```
String value = "hello";
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name",value);
    startActivity(intent);
```

then get the value in MainActivity;

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String myData = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```